# Use random file

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```
com = "node file1.js {var1} {var2} {var3} {var4} {var5}".format(
    var1 = self.CURRENTENTRY[0],
    var2 = self.CURRENTENTRY[1],
    var3 = self.CURRENTENTRY[2],
    var4 = self.CURRENTENTRY[3],
    var5 = ",".join(elist)
)
```

I would like to use more .js files (file2.js, file3.js, ..., filex.js) and let the script to chose one at random each time.

Comment: Use the `random.select()` function.

Comment: Note that creating a command through string concatenation is a fast route to security bugs. If your `CURRENTENTRY` array contains `; rm -rf ~/*;`, you're going to have a very bad day if code is passing that command to a shell. And even if you use `shlex.split()`, an entry with spaces or other syntactically-relevant characters can still do surprising/unexpected things.

Comment: ...in general, you should generate commands _as lists of arguments_ -- that's the way they're internally represented on sane (which is to say, non-Windows) operating systems anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code.

```
import random

files = ['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js']

filename = random.choice(files)
com = "node {filename} {var1} {var2} {var3} {var4} {var5}".format(
        filename,
        va1 = self.CURRENTENTRY[0],
        var2 = self.CURRENTENTRY[1],
        var3 = self.CURRENTENTRY[2],
        var4 = self.CURRENTENTRY[3],
        var5 = ",".join(elist)
    )
```

Comment: yes you need to look for indentations here

Comment: thank you, worked

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

foo = ["file2.js", "file3.js","file4.js"]
print(random.choice(foo))
```